# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to implement PayPal Button on my site, but somehow something is going wrong. I have checked my code over and over. Also researched other potential solutions, but can't get it to work. When I do a get request in Postman I get a nice response.

The error it trows is:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')

In my opinion get is not undefined and I handle the errors correctly.

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqjTF.png)

I have the following code:

*Express server.js*

```
app.get('/api/config/paypal', (req, res) =>{
    res.send(process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID || 'sb');
});
```

*OrderScreen.js*

```
export default function OrderScreen(){
    const params = useParams();
    const { id: orderId } = params;
    const [setSdkReady] = useState(false);

...

    useEffect(()=> {
        const addPaypalScript = async () => {
            const { data: clientId } = await Axios.get('/api/config/paypal')
            console.log(clientId);
            const script = document.createElement('script')
            script.type = 'text/javascript'
            script.src = `https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=${clientId}`
            script.async = true
            script.onload = () => {
              setSdkReady(true)
            }
            document.body.appendChild(script)
        }

        if(!order){
            dispatch(detailsOrder(orderId))
        }else if (!order.isPaid) {
            if (!window.paypal) {
              addPaypalScript()
            } else {
              setSdkReady(true)
            }
          }
    }, [dispatch, order, orderId, setSdkReady]);

...

return()

}
```

*In OrderActions.js*

```
export const detailsOrder = (orderId) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: ORDER_DETAILS_REQUEST, payload: orderId });
    const {
      userSignin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();
    try {
      const { data } = await Axios.get(`/api/orders/${orderId}`, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
      });
      dispatch({ type: ORDER_DETAILS_SUCCESS, payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message;
      dispatch({ type: ORDER_DETAILS_FAIL, payload: message });
    }
  };
```

Help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You should import `axios` with:

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

And use it like this (**lowercased**):

```
const { data: clientId } = await axios.get('/api/config/paypal')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved my issue!